# Auto press the spacebar key after every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I am using the impress.js and when ever the user presses the space bar, the script moves text around on the screen. Is there a way to have the spacebar be pressed every 5 seconds? Or is there a way to have the impress.js auto move onto the next slide ofter 5 seconds?

Comment: can you add a like to the page where you found this `impress.js`?

Comment: @bazzz Sure.... I got it from https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/

Answer (score 5):

The `impress.js` that you use has a `next()` function that is called upon pressing (amongst others) the spacebar key.
Possibly you could add a little javascript to call the `impress.next()` function every 5 seconds. Have a look at this:

```
setInterval ('impress.next()', 5000);  // 5000 milliseconds is 5 seconds
```

Here is a little explanation about the `setInterval()` function: [setInterval()](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/#alertTimerButton)